# Highcharts restrict tooltip hover when shared: true

Tags: javascript, highcharts, tooltip

Is there a way we can disable the hover functionality of highcharts tooltip when we enable
tootlip:{
shared: true
}.

The problem I am facing is tooltip is having the shared: true property and whenever i mouseover the chart one or other tooltips are showing and it seems to be annoying.I want to enable tooltip only when we hover over bar/column series, instead of covering the whole crosshair area.

Comment: can you please add what you have tried in JsFilddle?

Comment: Have you considered to disable `mouseTracking` for the series which the tooltip you don't want to show? API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.enableMouseTracking